# The Outlook data file (.pst) failed to load for this session

Tags: c#, outlook

i am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook Version 12.0.0.0  to read my outlook pst file but when compiler reaches this code  `outlookNs.AddStore(pstFilePath);`  it gives exception that 
         "The Outlook data file (.pst) failed to load for this session."  i have tried `outlookNs.AddStoreEx(pstFilePath);` also but the error was same ....any sugession ??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace PSTReader {
    class Program {
        static void Main () {
            try {
                IEnumerable<MailItem> mailItems = readPst(@"C:\temp\PST\Test.pst", "Test PST");
                foreach (MailItem mailItem in mailItems) {
                    Console.WriteLine(mailItem.SenderName + " - " + mailItem.Subject);
                }
            } catch (System.Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<MailItem> readPst(string pstFilePath, string pstName) {
            List<MailItem> mailItems = new List<MailItem>();
            Application app = new Application();
            NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            // Add PST file (Outlook Data File) to Default Profile
            outlookNs.AddStore(pstFilePath);
            MAPIFolder rootFolder = outlookNs.Stores[pstName].GetRootFolder();
            // Traverse through all folders in the PST file
            // TODO: This is not recursive, refactor
            Folders subFolders = rootFolder.Folders;
            foreach (Folder folder in subFolders) {
                Items items = folder.Items;
                foreach (object item in items) {
                    if (item is MailItem) {
                        MailItem mailItem = item as MailItem;
                        mailItems.Add(mailItem);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Remove PST file from Default Profile
            outlookNs.RemoveStore(rootFolder);
            return mailItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, and the below is what I did.

When you are saying outlookNs.AddStore, you have to give path and the file name.
and then in the outlookNs.Stores, the variable pstName should have any extension as .pst, you have to remove it.

Below is the sample on how I got it worked.

```
public class Mail
{
    public MailItem mailItem { get; set; }
    public String path { get; set; }
}


public static class Mails
{
    public static List<Mail> readPst(string pstFilePath, string pstName)
    {
        List<Mail> mail = new List<Mail>();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        // Add PST file (Outlook Data File) to Default Profile
        outlookNs.AddStore(pstFilePath + pstName);

        string storeInfo = null;

        foreach (Store store in outlookNs.Stores)
        {
            storeInfo = store.DisplayName;
            storeInfo = store.FilePath;
            storeInfo = store.StoreID;
        }

        MAPIFolder rootFolder = outlookNs.Stores[pstName.Substring(0,pstName.Length-4)].GetRootFolder();

        // Traverse through all folders in the PST file
        Folders subFolders = rootFolder.Folders;

        foreach (Folder folder in subFolders)
        {
            ExtractItems(mail, folder);
        }
        // Remove PST file from Default Profile
        outlookNs.RemoveStore(rootFolder);
        return mail;
    }

    private static void ExtractItems(List<Mail> mailItems, Folder folder)
    {
        Items items = folder.Items;

        int itemcount = items.Count;

        foreach (object item in items)
        {
            if (item is MailItem)
            {
                MailItem mailItem = item as MailItem;
                Mail mail = new Mail();
                mail.mailItem = mailItem;
                mail.path = folder.FolderPath + folder.Name;
                mailItems.Add(mail);
            }
        }

        foreach (Folder subfolder in folder.Folders)
        {
            ExtractItems(mailItems, subfolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the PST is read only or already open in a another process? Outlook needs readwrite permissions to the PST file, regardless of what you intend to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today! Searched high and low for an answer without success.

Eventually, we figured out that my user login credentials had read-permissions to the folder structure containing the PST file, while another user in my organization did not. She received the above error until we changed the permissions on the directory to allow read access, and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, neither credentials were the issue nor that the PST file was opened in another process.  I could not figure out what caused this but ...

... solution for me was to open Outlook->New Items->More Items->Outlook Data File...
[image]

In the popup, select Outlook data file (.pst) and hit OK
[image]

This will open Windows Expolorer, navigate to the location where your PST used to be created, name your PST file the way you used to name it and save it to that location.  Make sure you save as type Outlook Data File (*.pst).

Restart Outlook

This should restart outlook and your PST should be loaded now.  After this, I was also able to delete all from the location where my PST was located (including PST) and restarting outlook would not create it without any issues.